# How many users use browser's text search within a page?

Tags: website-design, browser

Do any significant number of users <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> macOS to activate browsers' text search?

I'm trying to find some usage numbers, but I can't find anything.

**Background**

I'm working on a page that has "hijacked" scroll events, which interferes with all native browser features that rely on scroll. This includes keyboard navigation, scrolling to anchors and page text search (and thus needs to be re-implemented, else have support dropped).

*Note: As some astute commenters guessed, I am not advocating this technique. I merely encountered it, felt it a poor risk/reward (for the same reasons mentioned below) and was seeking to help quantify the downsides.*

Comment: What are you replacing this functionality with? Most people don't use CTRL + F, but those of us who do expect it to find words on the page.

Comment: If you're pushing back against this, consider the effect on users with a disability, who may be protected (if not in law, by best practice).

Comment: The page you're working on sounds like it'll have a million other problems, too. Have you tried it with a screen-reader? Without CSS? With scripts disabled? At very high zoom/very low resolution? The simpler your webpage, the more likely you are to _automatically_ support all of that, with no effort from you.

Comment: It does not matter how many users use `Ctrl + F`. Those who don't, won't use your shortcut, because they don't use shortcuts at all. And those who will, expect `Ctrl + F` to still search a page, because they are used to use shortcuts. And Why hijacking `Ctrl + F` when you have millions of possible combinations to choose from? Don't rely on an old, probably useless research to justify hijacking `Ctrl +F`, it's just wrong.

Comment: Native behavior is the best UX - don't break your users expectations. I remember the 2000's when every Flash entry page had it's own implementation of scrolling/scroll bars. it was awful.

Comment: Note that some browsers also support typeahead, which starts a search as soon as something is typed on the keyboard, without having to press ctrl+f. I've had this enabled since Firefox 1, fifteen years ago. I seem to remember at least one popular website (github?) that interfered with that. Don't be that website which people remember for breaking native events.

Comment: Anyway, my point was simply that there are probably a significant number of users who use the find feature through the menu instead of using a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I think the real question is if _your_ users use and know about this feature. Setting up some kind of user behavior tracking on your page to measure this would be a good idea.

Comment: Just today I found a website where my browser (Firefox) was not working correctly using CMD+F on a specific webpage (a blog). I went and opened another browser (Chrome), loaded the same page and used CMD+F there, which thankfully worked as expexted. So yes, this is an awful user experience to force on your users. Imagine if CMD+F also did not work there and I tried Safari just to find out that didn't work either. The next step would be to open the web developer tools in Chrome or Firefox, copying the source to a text editor and doing a CMD+F there. Please do not ever block CMD+F or any other b

Comment: It seems like your actual question might be how can you help to dissuade someone from developing this hijacking technique. As one of the users who does frequently use ctrl-f, if I happened upon a site that intentionally broke it, I would almost certainly never return.

Comment: What does your page contain? Personally, I use that feature, but mostly on reddit, slashdot, and news articles. I suppose I use it also on PDFs and terms of services, but I think that's it.

Comment: Not really an answer but I should point out that I, personally, don't use `ctrl + f` unless I have to. Personally I use the `/` key which opens the "quick find" box in Firefox and automatically jumps to the first match for whatever text I start typing. It's a lot quicker and less cumbersome to use than `ctrl + f`. The reason why I bring this up is because I find that a lot of pages hijack the `/` key to move the input focus to the website's search box (e.g. GitHub and the PHP documentation site do this) and I find this behavior incredibly disruptive.

Comment: Browsers are already starting to prevent such things: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380637

Comment: @MichealJohnson - That's funny, I find it incredibly disruptive when I type a `/` to move the focus/cursor to the search box, and for some strange and unexpected reason, the "quick find" box opens instead =).

Comment: @MichealB I'd probably never return as well. I may also discourage other people from using the site - either actively or passively (by suggesting some other site that has the same purpose) - as well. The kind of "power" users who utilise keyboard shortcuts are also the kind of people less technical people will ask for advice, suggestions, etc. You may not just be turning away people who need/use that functionality by implementing things like that.

Comment: FWIW, it took me about a week to implement my own find/replace/scroll-to mechanism. 40 hours of doing nothing else. I needed to do find/replace on a list that'd load more at certain thresholds. That was greenfield development, though. Doing it in an existing system would be much more difficult, I imagine.

Comment: We used to do something like this, long before my time, thankfully. I found code that had a whole structure for which key codes should do what, but the keyboard events were entirely overridden and rewritten, from scratch. Thankfully, we don't do that anymore.

Comment: @isanae as someone who uses push-to-talk when in voice chat applications: Yes,Github. It does exactly what you wrote: It grabs keyboard input and tries to search the active repository. fsck them.

Comment: Let me just say that as other people have said, *breaking user expectations is a **bad idea***. I know too many sites that mess with scroll speed for "smooth scroll" or "snap to section" via JavaScript, and I can tell you that **I hate those websites with a burning passion**. I don't care how good your site/service is - if you are breaking the way things *naturally* are in terms of browser behavior, I hate your service. I'm a developer so maybe it infuriates me more, but I can imagine it frustrates a good number of "normal" people too.

Comment: @MichealJohnson thankyou - I never knew about that shortcut.  I'm very happy now.

Comment: @Baldrickk ...until you realise how many sites hijack it, that is...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Found an article sourcing a study conducted by Google in 2011 in the US. Apparently, 90% of the participants didn't know about it.

> "90 percent of the US Internet population does not know that. This is on a sample size of thousands," Russell said. "I do these field studies and I can't tell you how many hours I've sat in somebody's house as they've read through a long document trying to find the result they're looking for. At the end I'll say to them, 'Let me show one little trick here,' and very often people will say, 'I can't believe I've been wasting my life!'"

Source: https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/08/crazy-90-percent-of-people-dont-know-how-to-use-ctrl-f/243840/

Comment: I think it is kinda important to point out that this is about **US users only**. I'm not saying there are gonna be huge differences, but some cultural differences probably do exist.

Comment: Absolutely, and it's also important to point out that their sample could have been non tech savvy people. I can't tell for sure because I couldn't find the actual study now.

Comment: And keep in mind that the article is from 2011; the Google survey may be a bit older yet. It's absolutely possible that the numbers don't reflect today's usage anymore.

Comment: It does not matter how big the sample is or how reliable the study is, we all know that what he did is wrong and thus he should not be encouraged, your answer is encouraging him, If I were you I would delete the answer. God knows how many people will follow his steps after reading that

Comment: @Lynob Your comment (to me) appears to make no sense at all. Can you elaborate on what you mean? Who is the "he" you refer to and what did he do "wrong", and why is this answer "encouraging him"?

Comment: @JBentley the OP broke the `ctrl+F` and instead of fixing it, he's trying to see how many people use it. Rob tells him not to worry because 90% of users don't know about that shortcut and he doesn't mention that the study is useless because it was done so long ago. The OP then accepts the answer believing it to be true and doesn't fix the problem. Future users will see the answer, think that it is correct because it is highly rated and accepted, and might decide to break `Ctrl +F`. If you tell convince reader that only 10% use the shortcut, so it's not that important lets break it.

Comment: @Lynob (1) The question is about usage stats, not about whether it is a good idea to break functionality. The OP's motivations for asking the question aren't relevant (2) The answer does not in any way state "not to worry" or give any kind of recommendation. It merely states the stats. (3) The article was written in 2011 so I'm not sure where you're getting that it is useless because it was done "so long ago". I think your concerns are valid insofar as they relate to the OP, but they are addressed in the comments there and do not invalidate this answer.

Comment: @RobE Yep, my bad, didn't scroll all the way up! I moved the comment.

Comment: "not to worry because 90% of users don't know about that shortcut" - I have to admit I read 90% and thought "that means 10% know about it and presumably use it". Screwing up for 10% of your users is a *huge* amount. I personally read this as saying you *should* worry about it and I'm surprised that it was read otherwise.

Answer (score 97):

#### To answer the question you asked:

Keyboard shortcuts tend to be used by only a small subset of people ("power users"). This is a pretty set-in-stone shortcut—if an application responds to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, it will <sub><sup>(almost)</sup></sub> always trigger a "find" feature. Replacing a browser's find-in-page function with anything other than a custom find-in-page function would be unexpected.

Additionally, you'd only be interrupting your tech-savvy users (the ones who'd be inclined to use such a shortcut in the first place) while not providing any benefit to those who don't use keyboard shortcuts.

#### To answer the question you didn't ask:

Maybe I'm biased as a software engineer, but I cringed when I read "hijacked events".

**Hijacking common shortcuts *automatically* means that things aren't going to do what users expect them to do.** It's basically saying to your tech-savvy users "*I know what you wanted to do, buuuuut....*"

I'd caution you to only proceed with this if you're sure that what you're doing with these interactions is worth *forcefully redirecting* your users to your own features.

Comment: "Keyboard shortcuts tend to be used by only a small subset..." It's easy to confirm this by just watching people use their computers. I'm always surprised at how many people use mouse-drag in their scrollbars, even.

Comment: @KenMohnkern That hurts my heart.

Comment: @KenMohnkern As someone that is probably considered a power user - I drag the scrollbar around a lot. At times I also use middle-click and moving my mouse around. Everything has their use cases.

Comment: yeah, the momentum scroll is what I miss most when I have to use Linux/Windows...

Comment: Replacing the browser's find function *at all* is unexpected and obnoxious.

Comment: @TKK - it works perfectly fine for google docs.

Comment: How do you define "worthy"?

Comment: @Ooker I think that’s a decision that would require a lot more context, understanding of user goals, and user testing to be able to answer. To contrive an example, perhaps an online newspaper archive captures the CTRL + F shortcut which still finds results in the page, but also provides an option to include results from images on the page using automatic character recognition. Seems like a potentially worthy reason to intercept the shortcut.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be hijacking the keyboard shortcut, he's hijacking scrolling. So it will affect the `Find` feature whether they do it from the menu or a shortcut, and I think he's asking about them all.

Comment: When loading huge documents or disjoint documents (slideshow presentations) you often don't want them to all show up in the DOM at the same time, thus there is a very strongly defined need to "hijack" scrolling and in turn hijack the search function. Nothing wrong with hijacking it, you just have to be sure you are aligning with user expectations. When a user expects to find a search function it's bad to give him a broken search function just because you wished to keep it native.

Comment: The most annoying example I know of your "almost" in this answer actually comes from MS. In the earlier versions of Norwegian Excel/Word, the shortcuts for Bold and Find were changed around, probably because Bold in Norwegian is written "**Fet tekst**" - but whoever approved using Ctrl-B for Find should have set fire to his computer and started a flower shop.

Comment: @KenMohnkern my Father's PC has a broken scroll-wheel.  It doesn't always scroll when you spin it, and it will sometimes scroll the wrong way...  using the scrollbar is a necessity to get fast + accurate scrolling (page-up/down isn't fine-grained, and up and down keys don't always scroll (e.g. moving cursors) or scroll just a couple of lines at once.

Answer (score 19):

I think you asked the wrong question. It's not just the number of users that matter: you should consider the types of users you exclude too.

I literally used Ctrl+F to follow the link to this page. I'm a keyboard user with a slight difficulty in using the mouse. When I'm not already using the mouse for other reasons, when I want to follow a link in a browser in which I don't have any special extensions installed, I'll often press Ctrl+F, type enough of the text of the link to find it, press Escape to close the text search, then press Enter to follow the link.

It's not just the power users mentioned in another answer that you might think you're excluding. For the typical power user, the inability to use Ctrl+F is an inconvenience, nothing more than that. For people with more severe difficulties in using the mouse, attempts to hijack Ctrl+F may render your page completely unusable.

Only you can decide whether such people need to be able to use your site at all.

Comment: I really liked your way of using Ctrl+F to follow links.

Comment: This is not answering the question of how many people actually use this feature. There has been a note added to the question where they're not advocating these features and in fact are trying to *quantify the downside* of a page that does hijack these features, and hence need the numbers.

Comment: @doppelgreener They still need more than just numbers on how many people use this feature. They need to divide it at least in how many people use this feature but can live without it, and how many people use this feature and cannot live without it. Without that division, the numbers won't provide enough relevant information.

Comment: @hvd that is a fantastic ctrl-f usage - I'm definitely feeling one of the lucky 10,000 today (xkcd)

Comment: You might find Vimperator, Saka Key or similar browser addons useful.

Comment: @Ruslan I'm aware of them, thanks. Vimperator doesn't work on current versions of FF, so is not an option for me. Saka Key I do use, but it's sluggish on pages with a lot of links (SO!) and its injected HTML sometimes breaks sites. I do occasionally check if a new extension has been released that would work for me.

Comment: @Ruslan [Vimperator is pretty officially dead](https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/705#issuecomment-356432177) due to lack of WebExtension APIs and all the activity around all the alternatives that have popped up (see other comments on that issue).

Answer (score 3):

Adjunct: Those that do usually do because a (google or other) search for an exact term brought them to that page, and they want to jump straight to where the search phrase appears - either because

- they need the exact context of that search term (eg if the page is a table of part numbers or a dictionary)

or

- they have not yet established whether this search result, among other results, is worth further consideration - either because:

  - they suspect that 
    their search engine gave them a blind result. Google is very hard to keep from doing that these days - even "verbatim search" can give you useless results containing a variation of the search phrase
  - they fully expect search engine manipulation to happen regarding their query (eg cloaked pages)
  - their search phrase has a high rate of false positives, because it is commonly used as a forum signature, "boilerplate" text, part of sponsored content...

---

The kind of navigation you are implementing is also very annoying to users that actually want to eventually read ALL or A LOT of your existing content, since it makes it even harder to establish and keep a reading position.