# What percentage of average users know about Find (ctrl or cmd + f), and Find and Replace, native to applications?

Tags: browser, hci, statistics, wayfinding

I'm having trouble finding recent data on what percentage of average users use, or even know about, the Find feature native to most applications.

I recently found a mention of a white collar worker manually replaces all instances of a phrase in a long Word document because he didn't know about find-and-replace. It's basic computer literacy, but I wondered what the stats look like for people that:

- Know/don't know about Find
- Use the browser's native Find when using the web

I looked through some HCI papers and studies, but couldn't find much that's too definitive. I found this one anecdotal source from 2011 claiming that [90% of users don't know about Find](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/08/crazy-90-percent-of-people-dont-know-how-to-use-ctrl-f/243840/), which seems absurd, right?

For the sample, I'm looking for any population that represents average users of any country, or white-collar workers (i.e., those who have an office job)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many users use browser's text search within a page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/117505/how-many-users-use-browsers-text-search-within-a-page)

Comment: Just something for thought... I know about CTRL + F, yet I still somehow always forget to use it.

Comment: @Nash, FYI, that question's answer is the link in my question's body. Yeah, I was already aware of that off-hand 90%-ish metric. But it seemed really anecdotal. 

Anyways, doesn't matter now, because someone with high reputation decided to just close my question :(

Comment: @Orun Happens to the best of us. I also wish there was more accurate research on those kinds of questions out there.

Answer (score 0):

this can be answered better if we can add some fiter to the userbase

We also need to question how did we come to know about this shortcut. It was mostly because of

- working on some documentation
- finding a text something on a webpage

Now lets think on how many users do the above on a computer.
There are a lot of users who use computers within the boundaries of an application only where Ctrl+f is not required for examples legacy Inventory management on windows

hence those users even though they know how to run the app and get their work done might have never heard about the shortcuts.