# Browser shortcuts statistics

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Im looking for some statistical data about using shortcuts in Chrome or any other browser. What users use the most and the least? haven't found anything on the web, anyone got an idea where can I get some info about this?

Comment: There is a [thread about the usage of browser search (CTRL/CMD+F)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/117505/how-many-users-use-browsers-text-search-within-a-page). Even for such a well known feature there is not a lot of data out there. I am afraid it won't be better for other shortcuts.

Comment: You will probably need to control for outliers like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl+Z: things that are not technically browser shortcuts, but are still shortcuts used while using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I went searching through where Google publish their research information at [Google Research](https://research.google/) and also browsed the site. I think if there's anything published from a credible source that's where it would be located/found.

Having said that, I think there are a number of reasons why you wouldn't find anything (at least too specific) on this area because the amount of data that would have to be analysed, and exactly what information that would be used for or how it would be interpreted are all things that I would be wondering about as well.

I think there are a lot of different contexts that would need to be considered as well, such as the difference in mobile versus desktop, type of device and what type of sites people are visiting. Generalising this into a few stats or values doesn't seem to make much sense unless you had a question you want to address/answer in mind.